# CD4043 latch breadboard VS PCB

Tags: switches, latch, reset

I am working on a circuit that contains CD4043 R/S latch. The design on the breadboard works and everything is great, as soon as the PCB was manufactured and components were soldered, an issue with the latch arose.

[image: Cirucit diagram]

I use the switch-button on the SET input to initialize the latch and for the restart. But somehow on the output, I always get 0 with no matter what is on RESET input. The exception is when the button is actually pressed, then I have 5V.

However, as I said before, there were no problems on the breadboard.

What I did, but it doesn't help:

1. All the unused latch inputs connected to the ground.
2. Decoupling capacitors across VCC and ground.
3. The design itself based on logic components. Calculated delay times, there should be still enough time for the latch to recognize 5V from the switch, but it somehow doesn't 'hold' it.
4. First used SPDT switch, then replaced it with single pole switch + resistor, to avoid open circuit state at the moment of switch.

Nothing has helped :'( :'( :'(

Please advice. If you need extra details I am ready to provide.

EDIT 1: I attached the actual electrical circuit to make it clear.
[image: Circuit with single pole switch mentioned in 4.]

EDIT 2: I need the latch output to depend not only on the input signals (A and B in U3), but also on its own output, i.e. if at least one of the input signals is off, the latch goes to 0. As soon as input signals are back, the latch should stay in 0 state until it's initialized with the switch S1.

Comment: Are you sure that's really the circuit you've built? There are a few things wrong with it (such as the switch shorting out the supply and the transistor sorting the output of the 1st gate to ground.

Comment: I inserted a picture. The transistor is used as a switch. As well as a switch - to initialize the latch and reset the SET input if I can say so.

Comment: Ok - the addition of all those resistors which are not present in your original sketch make a big difference.

Comment: Better , but NEVER  leave CMOS inputs floating and missing decoupling cap (>=0.01uF)  WHy because when logic gate switches it discharges xx pF on Vdd to Vss per gate and then Vdd can get noisy

Comment: Missing connection from Transistor Out and S1 needs a cap across switch for POR

Comment: It is very hard to explain your design because the schematic does not follow conventional  logical.  Don't worry. You'll learn after reading old National Semiconductor manuals on Archive.org for CD4000 logic how it's done.  or similar good sources not youtube.  You have a positive feedback loop and latency is killing it .. Use a D FF clock input EDGE instead of a State to avoid the Positive Feedback "metastable" or RACE condition Transistor Inverts and R to Q bar Inverts in a loop when switch is released, Q goes to 0

Comment: Test my understanding by looking at the signals when switch is closed  Then scrap the LATCH design and use edge trigger FF

Comment: Aside from anything else, you show no pull up/down resistors. Is S4 input floating ? Not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd way to do what you are trying with feedback to edge trigger to use a CD4000 series latch (old tech) then using an NPN to shunt the input NAND gate.

A better question might show the timing diagram you want to design or a truth table or a State Diagram. You just want a Power on Reset (POR) with a 2-OR input=0 Latch from 1 to 0. There are many ways to do this without a transistor shorting the output even though the old CD4000 series is only 300 Ohms to 1k output Z while 74HC is ~ 50 Ohms.

- My guess is you overlooked that both latch and FF outputs are high when both inputs are On.
- Or you changed the 3 input NAND logic family to 74HCxx and the NPN base R is too high and perhaps 470R might do the trick. Check Vce.

If inductive circuit delay of some xx ns made your breadboard work try adding an xxx pF cap to the transistor to suppress crosstalk.

[image]

[image]

---

### Better Way. Although POR stays low is better than Power On Set.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjMePz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I need my latch to depend not only on the input signals but also on its own output. I.e. if one of the input signals off and then immediately back, I want the latch to stay on its 0 state.

Comment: I might not understand what you mean under your bullets.

But all the inputs and outputs are measured several times. Everything looks fine on RESET input. 



And do you mean that using the CD4000 family which is old tech influences the circuit functionality?

And as I mentioned before the circuit works on the breadboard, but not on the PCB

Comment: When both SR are high, both outputs are high, what latency effects during race condition going off?  All you need is a POR and an edge triggered Clock FF not a latch with loopback

Comment: The breadboard is different why, Impedance and inductance delays, stray crosstalk?

Comment: I have no idea what is different about the breadboard compared to PCB. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Wire is 10nH/cm , trace capacitance depends on length and gap to gnd. Saturn PCB design .exe free will teach you assuming you used same parts. you can also simulate your design in Falstad  if you understand crosstalk pF and ESL and add driver R

Comment: but how to introduce the trace capacitance to the PCB to check if it's a matter?

Comment: Scope RSQQ!....with manual trigger on Q=0, but your schematic is incomplete. decoupling caps POR? Vcc 3-NAND

Comment: Can you not view signals when Switch is pressed then released to capture 100ns /div with 20MHz filter on and short Gnd probe lead  ????

Comment: Any questions?.....l

Comment: Not yet. Thank you

Comment: understood yet?

Comment: Is there any reason why activating a switch I would get a periodic pulse signal on the SET pin and on the Q pin consequently?

Comment: @IvetaS  The switch ought to be tied to Vdd when closed and pulled down to 0V with R1 when open. So nothing obvious going on here. How about there? Can you trace where it comes from?

Comment: I chose CD74HC74, so I have the opposite to what you wrote.
It is always the pulse on SET when Clk = 0, but it is 5V when clk = 5 until the switch is closed.

Comment: okHC74 has Reset,Set=0 (neg. logic) so pullup R and switch to gnd?  Is reset active =0 or 1? then choose appropriate input/output

Comment: exactly.

Seems like each button activation gives a pulse. When clk is changed (both 0 and 5), Q is a constant signal (=0 always)

Comment: With inverted logic change D to 1. Beyond this I don't know what you need